# How do I make a function of a namespace inaccessible by the client side

Tags: c++, class, oop, namespaces

I'm writing a class which is wrapped in a `namespace` named `cs`. I am using a library whose one of the function takes a `function pointer`. The function have to modify some of the protected members of the class so I wrote a free function in the same `cs` namespace and made it a `friend function` of the class. Doing that made it available for the clients to use that function. But The function MUST be inaccessible from the client due to obvious reasons.

An example code is here:

```
#include "lib.h"
namespace cs{
   class A
   {
     protected:
      int x;
      float y;
      friend int myFunc(void* userdata, int valInt, float valFloat);
     public:
      void abc()
      {
        libFunc(this, myFunc);
      }    
   };
   void myFunc(void *userdata, int x, float y){
       // I would like this function to be inaccessible from the client
       A *obj = (A*) userdata;
       obj->x = x;
       obj->y = y;
     }
}
```

Comment: In short you cannot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So any other way to work around this?

Comment: Instead of a `friend` function you can make it a private `static` function of your class.

Comment: Hell, that was really easy. Static did not come to my mind while doing it. Thanks please post it as an answer so that I can accept it @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: In case you really need free function, you can use nested `namespace detail` or something similar. User still can call it, but this convention is often used in header-only libraries to hide implementation details..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a free function inaccessible in another compilation unit, you may use a nested [anonymous namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces):

```
namespace cs{

   class A
   {
     protected:
        //...
        friend int myFunc(int valInt, float valFloat);
     public:
        void abc();
   };

   namespace {  // anonymous nested namespace
        int myFunc(int x, float y){
           ...
     }
   }

   void A:: abc() {
        libFunc(this, myFunc);
   }    
}
```

Comment: Yep it does. But i accepted this one as @πάντα ῥεῖ didn't posted it as an answer